# array in foreach loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm taking data from mysql database table. The table have **ID** and **"POST"** columns. I've ordered **posts** by **id**'s from bottom so i always have the newest post on the first place. But when i want to **echo** specific post (eg. with id 5) i can't **echo it** with `$col = mysqli_fetch_array($result); echo $col;`. I've tried with **foreach loop** but it **echo**'s all posts. So I thought if i could put them into **array** with **foreach loop** it would do the job.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `post` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$col = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

foreach($col as $cols) {

}
```

I've tried a lot of things and spent a lot of time on research but still don't have idea how to do it.

Thanks for your ideas and help.

Comment: You should write `$cols as $col` instead of `$col as $cols` and accordingly renaming  `$col = ` into `$cols = `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `post` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$col = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

foreach($col as $cols) {
    if($col['id'] == 5) {
        print_r($col);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I've tried this: `while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $cols[] = $col;
    }

    foreach($cols as $col)
    {
        if($col['id'] == 2) {
            print_r($col);
        }
    }`  but  from that I get this: **Array ( [id] => 2 [post] => goodbye all )**. And I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

If you want to get a specific post, you have to change your SQL to something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `id` = $wanted_post_id";
```

Comment: So you mean that I have to write `echo $col['post'];` but that echo's all data from column **post**. The problem is that I need only specific row from that column in each **div**.

Comment: Sorry @Gerald Schneider, I missunderstood the question.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say that I need them all on the one place first and then optionally put specific row to specific div.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_fetch_array fetchs a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both.
You need to specify the name of the column you want to print out.
Because you may have more than one row in your result set, you should use a loop (`while`) like so:

`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['POST']; // 'POST' here is the name of the column you want to print out
}`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea, I know how to echo column but I have to echo 1 row in column "post"